# how to use isdigit() in C

Tags: c

So I'm trying to use a isdigit() to check for non numeric values and for some reason when I put in a integer i get a floating exception error and my generated printf statement "invalid input". I am quite confused on why when i enter a digit it goes into my if statement where it is only true if it is NOT an integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int hour=0, minute=0, total=0, maxDiveTime=0, counter=0, average=0;
  printf ("Enter dive times in the format of HH:MM (hours:minutes), Enter \\0 to stop\n");
  while (scanf("%d:%d",&hour, &minute) != '\0')
  {
    if ((!isdigit(hour)) || (!isdigit(minute)))
    {
      printf("Invalid Input\n");
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      if (((hour*60)+minute) > (maxDiveTime))
      {
        maxDiveTime = ((hour*60)+minute);
      }
      total = total + (hour*60) + minute;
      counter ++;
    }
  }
    average = total/counter;
    printf("The total divetime is %d:%d\n", total/60, total%60);
    printf("The average divetime is %d:%d\n", average/60, average%60);
    printf("The max divetime is %d\n", maxDiveTime );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know, each standard (and not that standard too) function has a comprehensive documentation readily available. Try [`man isdigit`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit)

Comment: What makes you think that the return value of `scanf` will ever be equal to `\0`? Did you try reading **any** documentation at all when you ran into the error?

Comment: @KenWhite Input like "++" will cause `scanf("%d:%d",&hour, &minute)` to return 0.

Comment: An `int` is an `int`. Calling `isdigit()` with an argument of type `int` does not do what you want. `isdigit()` takes a _character_ as an argument and it will tell you if it is a numeric character, you know, `'0'` ... `'9'`. The fact that `isdigit()` is documented as taking an argument of type `int` instead of `char` is a historical accident.

Comment: @chux: And the proper way to write that comparison would be `!= 0`.

Comment: @KenWhite `0` vs `'\0'` is a style issue - both are `int` with a value of 0.  Certainly `scanf("%d:%d",&hour, &minute) == 2` is preferable.

Comment: @rodrigo a C standard function taking `int` instead of `char` in not accidental.  None of those functions take a `char`.  `int` is used for performance and simplification.  `isdigt(int)` is defined for `unsigned char` values and `EOF`, too many for a `char`.  Works well with the return values from `fgetc()`.

Comment: @chux: Yeah, and that's why doing `isdigit('é')`, for example, is undefined, but `isdigit(-1)` is fine, which I wouldn't call it sensible design... The `EOF` might be useful as a sentinel return value (for `getc()` for example) but as input argument is rather useless.

Comment: the \0 is just used for when they want to stop inputting dive times, the program is just to input dive times and calculate the average, max dive time , and total dive time, but I need to make sure the input is in the format h:m (hour:minutes), is there a better way to check for non numeric chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason for the floating exception is that `count` in expression `total/count` is zero when you break when entering the loop the first time or when you do not enter the loop at all. So check `count` before calculating something. Second, `scanf` returns the number of values successfully read in, which should be `2` in your case. Third, `isdigit` expects a character, i.e. something like `'0'`, not an integer ranging from `0` to something. When `scanf` with `%d` succeeds, you have already successfully read in a number (and nothing else).

```
int main()
{
  int hour=0, minute=0, total=0, maxDiveTime=0, counter=0, average=0;
  printf ("Enter dive times in the format of HH:MM (hours:minutes), Enter \\0 to stop\n");
  while (scanf("%d:%d",&hour, &minute) == 2)
  {
      if (((hour*60)+minute) > (maxDiveTime))
      {
        maxDiveTime = ((hour*60)+minute);
      }
      total = total + (hour*60) + minute;
      counter ++;
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    average = total/counter;
    printf("The total divetime is %d:%d\n", total/60, total%60);
    printf("The average divetime is %d:%d\n", average/60, average%60);
    printf("The max divetime is %d\n", maxDiveTime );
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer although it loses OP's apparent goal of detecting  "invalid input".

Comment: so i guess what i can do is typecast hour and minute to be chars?

Comment: @EddyY No!  Since you read the input using `%d`, it's already guaranteed to be numeric.  `%d` parses valid input, or nothing.  It's not possible for an `int` variable to contain something other than a number.  As someone already explained, calling `isdigit()` on these numbers does not do what you thought, and casting them to `char` wouldn't do that, either.  Suppose you read in the time 38:59.  If you cast the integer 38 to `char`, you'll get `&` (which is not a digit).  If you cast the integer 49 to `char`, you'll get `;` (which is not a digit, either).

Comment: @SteveSummit a good alternative to checking for invalid inputs

Comment: @EddyY Sorry, I still don't understand what you're asking, but whatever it is, this comment thread probably isn't the best place for it; you should probably post a brand-new question.  In this question you were asking why `isdigit` didn't work, but it turned out that -- in this case -- you don't have to check for digits, because scanf `%d` is basically already doing that for you.

Comment: @EddyY If you post another question, you should be clear what you want to do: (1) keep calling scanf, but do some different validation (other than checking for digits, which scanf is already doing) or some better handling of scanf's failure if the input does not contain digits, or (2) do your input and your validation using some technique(s) not involving scanf. (For question (2), my answer would involve: (a) `fgets`; (b) a way to break strings up based on whitespace or delimiters, perhaps based on `strtok` or the like; and finally, (c) functions like `atoi` and `strtol`.)